# interior points having some distance from the boundary.

Tags: general-topology

Let $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ be open, and let $U_\epsilon:=\{ x\in U | d(x,\partial U)>\epsilon\}$. Is it true that $(U_\epsilon)_\delta=U_{\epsilon+\delta}$? I tried to prove it, but I couldn't, and also I couldn't find a counterexample. Please give me any advice.

**Edit** I showed that $(U_\epsilon)_\delta \supset U_{\epsilon+\delta}$. But $(U_\epsilon)_\delta \subset U_{\epsilon+\delta}$ is troublesome.

<strike>My trial: Let $x \in (U_\epsilon)_\delta$, i.e.  $x \in U_\epsilon \subset U, d(x,\partial U_\epsilon) := \gamma > \delta$. I proved as a lemma that if $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ is closed, $d(x,A) = \epsilon \Rightarrow \exists y \in A$ such that $d(x,y)= \epsilon$. Hence we have $d(x,y)=\gamma$ for some $y \in \partial U_\epsilon$. This implies $d(y, \partial U)= \epsilon$ (proof omitted), hence $d(y,z)=\epsilon$ for some $z \in \partial U$. I claim that $d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ so $d(x,\partial U) \ge d(x,z) \ge \epsilon+\gamma > \epsilon+\delta$. But I don't know how to prove the claim.</strike>

Is there any hint or maybe a counterexample?

I proved it, leaving it as an answer.

Comment: I suppose we're using the standard (Euclidean) distance?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes.

Comment: Then the identity $(1)$ from Hagen's answer holds (it holds for all metrics induced by a norm), and that, along the characterisation $$x\in U_\varepsilon \iff \overline{B_\varepsilon(x)} \subset U,$$ is the key to prove the equality.

Comment: @DanielFischer In here, I don't know how to prove $\Rightarrow$ direction. All looks plausible when I just draw a picture, but I don't know how to rigorously state it.

Comment: Contrapositive. If $\overline{B_\varepsilon(x)} \not\subset U$, there are two possibilities, a) $x\notin U$, and then a fortiori $x\notin U_\varepsilon$, b) $x\in U$; since the ball is connected, it follows that $\overline{B_\varepsilon(x)} \cap \partial U \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: I proved it: Let $x \in U_\epsilon$. If $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)} \cap \partial U \neq \emptyset$, say $y \in \partial U$ and $d(x,y) \le \epsilon$, then $d(x, \partial U) \le \epsilon$, contradiction to $x \in U_\epsilon$. So $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)} \cap \partial U = \emptyset$. Then $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)} \cap U$ and $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)} \cap \overline{U}^c$ are two open sets of $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)}$ which is connected. Since $x \in U$, $x$ lies in the former, so we have $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)} \cap U = \overline{B_\epsilon(x)}$, i.e. $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)} \subset U$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $U_\epsilon=U\setminus\bigcup_{x\notin U} \overline{B(x,\epsilon)}$. The claim then follows from the observation that $$\overline{B(x,\epsilon+\delta)}=\bigcup_{y\in \overline{B(x,\epsilon)}}\overline{B(y,\delta)}\tag1$$

---

Note that the claim (and hence $(1)$) does not hold in general metric spaces: Let $X=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and $U=X\setminus \{-1\}$. Then

- $\partial U=\{-1\}$,
- $U_1=(-\infty,-2)\cup (0,\infty)$,
- $\partial U_1=\{-2\}$,
- $(U_1)_1=(-\infty,-3)\cup(0,\infty)$,
- but $U_2=(-\infty-3)\cup (1,\infty)$.

---

Comment: How can you show that $U_\epsilon=U\setminus\bigcup_{x\notin U} \overline{B(x,\epsilon)}$ especially, $\subset$ direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'll prove only $(U_\epsilon)_\delta \subset U_{\epsilon+\delta}$. Suppose $x \in (U_\epsilon)_\delta$, so $x \in U_\epsilon \subset U$, $d(x, \partial U_\epsilon):=\gamma>\delta$. For any $z \in \partial U$, consider the line segment $[x,z]:=\{ tx+(1-t)z \mid 0 \le t \le 1 \}$. Note that $U_\epsilon$ is open, so $[x,z] \cap U_\epsilon$, $[x,z] \cap \overline{U_\epsilon}^c$ are open sets of $[x,z]$ each containing $x, z$. If $\partial U_\epsilon \cap [x,z] = \emptyset$, contradiction occurs since $[x,z]$ is connected. Thus $\exists y \in [x,z]$ such that $y \in \partial U_\epsilon$, which implies $d(y,\partial U) = \epsilon$ (proof omitted), so $d(y,z) \ge \epsilon$. Note that $d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ since $y \in [x,z]$ and $d(x,y) \ge \gamma$ since $d(x,\partial U_\epsilon)=\gamma$. Thus $d(x,z) \ge \gamma + \epsilon$. Taking infimum over $z \in \partial U$, $d(x,\partial U) \ge \gamma+\epsilon>\epsilon+\delta$.